# Error when using Paginator in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0, paginator

I have a variable $paginator for paginating data

In my Controller

```
public $paginator = [
    'limit'=>5,
    'order'=>[
        'author'=>'desc'
    ]
];
```

In my view-template (.ctp)

```
<?= $this->Paginator->prev('<< pre') ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->next('next >>')?>
<?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?>
```

But i receive many error:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: pageCount [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 591]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: count [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 595]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: perPage [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 598]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: count [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 599]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: count [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 600]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: page [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 613]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: current [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 615]
>   Notice (8): Undefined index: count [CORE/src/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php, line 616]

I recognize that only this row cause error

```
<?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?>
```

i can't paginate.
why does it such? :(

Comment: show your whole controller action for that view

Comment: oh. thank you.thank to you,i have seen my missing in my controller. i have't declared paginate $paginate = $this->paginate($this->Articles);
        $this->set(compact('$paginate'));

Comment: I figured that yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

In controller paginate property

```
public $paginate = [
        'States' => ['scope' => 'states'],
        'Lgas' => ['scope' => 'lgas'],
];
```

In controller action

```
  $lgas = $this->paginate($this->Lgas, ['scope' => 'lgas']);
  $states = $this->paginate($this->States, ['scope' => 'states']);
  $this->set(compact('lgas', 'states'));
```

In View

```
<div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?=$this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('first'), ['model' => 'Lgas', 'tab' => 'lga'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), ['model' => 'Lgas', 'tab' => 'lga'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->numbers(['model' => 'Lgas', 'tab' => 'lga'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', ['model' => 'Lgas', 'tab' => 'lga'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->last(__('last') . ' >>', ['model' => 'Lgas', 'tab' => 'lga'])?>
        </ul>
        <p><?=$this->Paginator->counter(['format' => __('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total'), 'model' => 'Lgas', 'tab' => 'lga'])?></p>
    </div>

    <div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?=$this->Paginator->first('<< ' . __('first'), ['model' => 'States'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), ['model' => 'States'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->numbers(['model' => 'States'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', ['model' => 'States'])?>
            <?=$this->Paginator->last(__('last') . ' >>', ['model' => 'States'])?>
        </ul>
        <p><?=$this->Paginator->counter(['format' => __('Page {{page}} of {{pages}}, showing {{current}} record(s) out of {{count}} total'), 'model' => 'States'])?></p>
    </div>
```